# Solving Persian Characters in Sublime Text With Bidirectional text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, bidirectional

I'm using sublime text v3 and find out there is a problem with persian characters in sublime text, i find the solution by using [Bidirectional text](https://github.com/praveenvijayan/Sublime-Text-2-BIDI) package

This is a image of my problem:

[image: This is a image of my problem]

But i have to use ctrl+b everytime i typing persian character.
Is there anyway that make Bidirectional text automaticly run on the codes and don't use ctrl+b everytime ?

Thanks.

Comment: I checked out **Bidirectional Text**, and don't completely understand what it does. Does it simply reverse the input direction of text, or is there more to it? Try adding 2 GIFs to your question to illustrate the issue. One that demonstrates the original issue without **BT**, and one that shows how you use **BT**. You can use something like [**ScreenToGif**](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/). It might be possible to write an event listener to trigger or recreate **BT**'s functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download this package:https://github.com/HosseinRashno/Sublime-Text-2-BIDI

then extract to sublime text package folder(in sublime text go to preference menu then click browse packages and extract package in to it)

exit from sublime text and run it again

write bidi text(etc persian or others) and right click and select bidi text.

and then it's work.

source:https://github.com/HosseinRashno/Sublime-Text-2-BIDI